# STATIC_URL is being overridden while using django-storages in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using this configuration in my `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ('storages',)
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
STATIC_URL = '//xyz.cloudfront.net/'
```

When I deploy the website, it still uses the s3 url instead of the cloudfront URL provided as `STATIC_URL`. Is there something wrong here?

Answer (score 9):

`STATIC_URL` is actually only used by default staticfiles storage or when staticfiles storage is not used at all. If `STATICFILES_STORAGE` is set, django will ask that class to provide valid URL. If you want to change your s3 domain, use `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` setting.

Comment: This is the real answer !

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with a change in the templates.

`static` from `{% load staticfiles %}` tells the storage engine to load the static url where as `static` from `{% load static %}` simply loads the `STATIC_URL` from the settings.